# Refresh page after selecting radio button but keep the radio button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a page where the user can select an option by clicking on a radio button. I want the page to refresh keeping the selected radio button value. These are my codes.

HTML

```
<div style="float:right">
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="f1">Option 1</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="f2">Option 2</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" value="f3">Option 3</label><br>
</div>

<div style="float:left;" class="f1 box">This is option 1</div>
<div style="float:left;" class="f2 box">This is option 2</div>
<div style="float:left;" class="f3 box">This is option 3</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="f1"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".f1").show();
        }

        if($(this).attr("value")=="f2"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".f2").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="f3"){
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".f3").show();
        }

    });
```

CSS

```
 .box{
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Is there a a way to reload just the div instead of refreshing the entire page?

Comment: You can't do this unless you persist the value, either by adding it as a query param to the url (maybe) or using storage (like local storage or a cookie)

Comment: I think you need a cookie.

Comment: also you should listen to change not click..

Comment: Is it okay to pass the param in the URL. If so, just use the window.location.

Comment: How do I pass the param in the URL?

Comment: Side note: Refreshing the whole page any time a radio button changes is a poor UX.  If you need to get updated data from the server, just get that data via AJAX and update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to refresh just the div after clicking the radio button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an HTML file, then use `localStorage` to store the `<input>` clicked by the `value` attribute and then when the page is loaded, run the `onclick` event of the right `<input>` element.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=\"radio\"]").click(function(){
        [...]
        //localStorage:
        localStorage.setItem("option", value);
    });
    //localStorage:
    var itemValue = localStorage.getItem("option");
    if (itemValue !== null) {
        $("input[value=\""+itemValue+"\"]").click();
    }
});
```

If this is run on a server, then use `document.cookie` to store the `<input>` clicked by the `value` attribute and when sending data to the client server-side, make the correct `<input>` checked and the correct box showing.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=\"radio\"]").click(function(){
        [...]
        //Cookies:
        document.cookie="option="+value;
    });
    //Cookies:
    /*Load the page with the correct input checked based off cookies*/
});
```

Here's the fiddle (unfortunately, cookies don't work here): http://jsfiddle.net/NobleMushtak/vTT7J/

Comment: How do I refresh page? Should I use onclick="windows.reload()" in the input?

Comment: _Don't_ do `onclick="location.reload()"` because that might get called the jQuery `click` event. Instead, put `location.reload()` at the end of your jQuery `click` event, after you've stored the value. I don't see why you'd need to do that, though. That's probably going to be inefficient and there might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

add `autocomplete='on'` attribute to your input field.

Answer (score 0):

As your page will be refreshed new  components will be created you can't persisit their value directly by using javascript , the value needs to be stored somewhere from where you can get your values later and reset value in your new radio button element.

In other words you want to save states of your objects in web application.For purpose of Maintaining state of object we have many methods as we often use request scope, Quesy String or a session.As your requirement is to save value only till next request(next page refresh) so for this purpose of maintaining that value for next page load you can use request scope or you need to add that value to your query string,in both of the ways you can get that value from request scope or query string and apply that value to your radio button.

> How do I pass data between JavaScript pages?

1. Submitting form data to a server-side script that then outputs a new JavaScript page containing the data. This is simple and reliable and works in all browsers, but requires support for server-side scripting of some kind (PHP, ASP, etc).
2. Passing form-style data in a URL to a new JavaScript page, without using any server-side scripts. This works in all browsers but supports a limited amount of data. It is the traditional way of solving the problem without server-side scripting.
3. Passing data via the window.name property. Although this is not the intended purpose of window.name, it seems to work quite well and supports larger amounts of data than the second method. And it works in Safari, Firefox, and Internet Explorer. So why not use it? Because it is highly insecure! If the user follows a link to another website that doesn't belong to you, that other website can still see the data stored in window.name, which was never meant to be a secure, site-specific property. So I strongly discourage the use of this method.

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing the page, you can use in jquery location.reload(). For storing the radio button value which is clicked, you need to store the data in the local storage if you are not using server.

Comment: how do i store the values in local storage?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
Check this link.. it will help u.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount
best example using local storage

Comment: Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions, do not support Web Storage.
else you need to use cookies .. these two are the options i know.. Else use server

Comment: Exact approach for this would be using query string or putting that value in request scope.Thats why they are made, to pass values from one page to other.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cookie when select radio button and then refresh the page.
When page loads again read the cookie value and select radio button according to cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

Load by `$("#divWhichExcludesRadiobutton").load("current/url");` or add next script in the head tag

```
var myVal;
$("body").load("current/url", function () { $('input[type="radio"]').val(myVal) });
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
       myVal = $(this).attr("value");
       if($(this).attr("value")=="f1"){
           $(".box").hide();
           $(".f1").show();
       }
       if($(this).attr("value")=="f2"){
           $(".box").hide();
           $(".f2").show();
       }
       if($(this).attr("value")=="f3"){
           $(".box").hide();
           $(".f3").show();
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to your problem: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/h2gA5/4/)

I used the localStorage to save which radioButton is checked with a fallback to cookies:

```
function saveData(key,value) {
   localStorage.setItem(key,value) || (document.cookie = key + "=" + value);
}
```

On page load, the data is loaded from the used storage to check the belonging button and to activate the appropriate box.

Plus I simplified your function setting the active box.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP looks like this

```
<input type="radio" id="aa" name="Options" value="val1">radio 1
<input type="radio" id="bb" name="Options" value="val2"> radio 2
<input type="radio" id="cc" name="Options" value="val3"> radio 3
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=\"radio\"]").click(function(){
        var thisElem = $(this);
        var value = thisElem.val();
   alert('value'+value);
        localStorage.setItem("option", value);

    });
    var itemValue = localStorage.getItem("option");
    if (itemValue !== null) {
        $("input[value=\""+itemValue+"\"]").click();
    }

});
```

On load of page radio button will not reset as your using local storage to retrieve.

This will solve the issue

Comment: Your effort is appreciated. However, if you could add some explanation to your answer would be helpful for those who would read in future.

Answer (score -1):

" class="fieldLabel"  valign="middle">' key="label.portin.country" />:

```
                    <nested:present name="VoyagerSession" property="accountSummaryInfo.mspSummaryInfo.countryList">
                    <html:select tabindex="7" size="1" property="country" styleClass="field"  onchange= "Javascript:getstateList();javascript:selectPortInType();"> 
                    <bean:define id="countrylist" name="VoyagerSession" property="accountSummaryInfo.mspSummaryInfo.countryList" type="java.util.List" />
                    <html:options collection="countrylist" property="key" labelProperty="value" />
                    </html:select>
                    </nested:present>  

                    </td>
                   <td width="20%" align="<%= session.getAttribute("pageRight")%>" class="fieldLabel" valign="middle"><bean:message bundle='<%=session.getAttribute("pageBundle").toString()%>' key="label.portin.state" />:&nbsp;</td>
                   <td width="30%" valign="middle" class="field">
                    <html:select size="1" property="state" styleClass="field"> 
                      <bean:define id="statelist" name="VoyagerSession" property="accountSummaryInfo.mspSummaryInfo.stateList" type="java.util.List" />
                      <html:options collection="statelist" property="key" labelProperty="value" />
                      </html:select>
                   </td>
                </tr>
```